# Floating button using angularjs and jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have been handed a task to implement a floating button that floats until it sees footer then it should sit on top of footer. I am new to angularjs and I have gotten it to work with the help of following jquery

```
  funtion isVisible(elment){
    var vpH = $(window).height(),
    st = $(window).scrollTop(),
    y = $(elment).offset().top;
    return y <= (vpH + st)
  }

 $(window).scroll(function() {
   if(isVisible($('#footer'))){
      $('#to-top').css('position','absolute');
      $('#to-top').css('bottom','60px');
    } else {
      $('#to-top').css('position','fixed');
      $('#to-top').css('bottom','0px');

    }
  }
```

This approach doesn not seem to work all the time.

1) when there is less content on the page, button overlaps with footer position is fixed.

2) At times while getting the data from server, if the page is populated using ng-epeat, then the button's position is absolute and i will have to scroll to adjust its position. (i guess this happens coz, for a fraction of second footer is visible, so the position becomes absolute)

Ideally i would like to compute the position of the button after the page loads. how can i do it.

Here is the plunker [1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/IwViMJRnK2aqi8PNqT6n?p=preview